# System of coupled nonlinear pdes with FEM (magneto-hydrodynamic mass transfer)

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, fluid-dynamics, mass-transport

## EDIT 01

See end of post for an update.

## Original Question

I'm trying to reproduce the magneto-hydrodynamic flow studied [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1933131) using the nonlinear FEM functionality, and have been having trouble implementing the Neumann boundary conditions.
Pardon the long post, tried formulating a minimally broken example but all the sub-parts appear to work on their own.
The main questions are:

1. Why doesn't the `Inactive` form work here? and is it necessary?
2. How does one specify generalized `NeumannValue`s in coupled pdes?

### Equations

The non-dimensionalized system is given by:

- Incompressible flow:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{Re} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{u} &= -\nabla p + \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{u} + (\boldsymbol{J} \times \hat{e}_z) \\
  \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u} &=0,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  where the last term $(\boldsymbol{J} \times \hat{e}_z)$ is the Lorentz force arising from an out-of plane magnetic field.
- Mass Transfer (due to convection, diffusion, and migration)
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{(Conservative\;form):}&\quad \mathrm{Pe} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}c_k + \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{N}_k =0 \\
  &\quad \boldsymbol{N}_k = \mathrm{Pe} \;\boldsymbol{u} c_k - D_k \nabla c_k -z_k D_k c_k \nabla V \\
  \mathrm{(Non-conservative\;form):}&\quad \mathrm{Pe} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}c_k + \nabla \cdot \left(- D_k \nabla c_k -z_k D_k c_k \nabla V \right) + \mathrm{Pe}\; \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla c_k  =0,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  where $c_k$, $N_k$, $D_k$, $z_k$ are the concentration, flux density, diffusivity, and charge of species $k$ respectively.
- Current Density (which enters the Navier-Stokes equation):
  $$
  \boldsymbol{J} = - \sum_{k=1}^N z_k \boldsymbol{N}_k
  $$
- Electro-neutrality
  $$
  \sum_{k=1}^N z_k c_k =0
  $$

which we can implement in *Mathematica* as-follows:

```
(*Non-conservative form*)
massTransport[pe_][species_] :=
 pe*{u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][
     c[species][t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
  Inactive[Div][-(d[species]*z[species]*c[species][t, x, y]*
       Inactive[Grad][V[t, x, y], {x, y}]) - 
    d[species]*Inactive[Grad][c[species][t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
  pe*Derivative[1, 0, 0][c[species]][t, x, y]
electroNeutrality[
  listOfSpecies_] := (z /@ listOfSpecies).(c[#][t, x, y] & /@ 
    listOfSpecies)

(*{Jx,Jy,0}\[Cross]{0,0,1} \[Rule] {Jy,-Jx}*)
horizontalCurrentDensity[
  listOfSpecies_] := (-z /@ 
     listOfSpecies).(pe u[t, x, y] c[#][t, x, y] - 
      d[#] Derivative[0, 1, 0][c[#1]][t, x, y] - 
      z[#] d[#] c[#][t, x, y] Derivative[0, 1, 0][V][t, x, y] & /@ 
    listOfSpecies)
verticalCurrentDensity[
  listOfSpecies_] := (-z /@ 
     listOfSpecies).(pe v[t, x, y] c[#][t, x, y] - 
      d[#] Derivative[0, 0, 1][c[#1]][t, x, y] - 
      z[#] d[#] c[#][t, x, y] Derivative[0, 0, 1][V][t, x, y] & /@ 
    listOfSpecies)

fluidFlow[rey_, pe_][listOfSpecies_] := {
  rey ( {u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y]) + 
   Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][p][t, x, y] - 
   verticalCurrentDensity[listOfSpecies],
  rey ({u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y]) + 
   Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][p][t, x, y] + 
   horizontalCurrentDensity[listOfSpecies],
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][v][t, x, y] + Derivative[0, 1, 0][u][t, x, y]}

fullSystemOfEquations[rey_, pe_][listOfSpecies_] := Append[
  Join[fluidFlow[rey, pe][listOfSpecies], 
   Activate[massTransport[pe] /@ listOfSpecies]], 
  electroNeutrality[listOfSpecies]]
```

#### First Question

Notice I had to wrap the `Inactive`'d `massTransport` equations in an `Activate` to avoid this error:
[image]
Not sure why?

### Geometry

We choose a simple system with a pair of parallel electrodes:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh=ToBoundaryMesh[
"Coordinates"->{{-2,-1/2},{-3/4,-1/2},{3/4,-1/2},{2,-1/2},{2,1/2},{3/4,1/2},{-3/4,1/2},{-2,1/2}},
"BoundaryElements"->{LineElement[{{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{6,7},{7,8},{8,1}}]},
"BoundaryGroupingThreshold"->1(*To specify electrodes w/ ElementMarker*)];
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle"->"BoundaryGrouping"]]
ColorData["BrightBands"]/@Most[Subdivide[Length[bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]]]]
emesh=ToElementMesh[bmesh,"MaxCellMeasure"->10^-3]
```

[image]

### System

We consider a system with three species (Fe$^{3+}$,Fe$^{2+}$,Cl$^{-}$), for the reaction:
$\mathrm{Fe}^{3+} + e^- \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Fe}^{2+}$

### Boundary Conditions

We apply no-slip boundary conditions for the fluid on the top and bottom of our channel, zero pressure drop across the inlet (left) and outlet (right) of our channel, and (generalized) Neumann boundary conditions with opposite signs on the top and bottom electrodes:

```
noSlipBC=DirichletCondition[{u[t,x,y]==0,v[t,x,y]==0},Or@@Thread[ElementMarker=={1,2,3,5,6,7}]];
pressureDropBC=DirichletCondition[p[t,x,y]==0,Or@@Thread[ElementMarker=={4,8}]];
cathode[Da_,k_,\[Alpha]_:1/2]=NeumannValue[Da(c["Fe3+"][t,x,y]Exp[-\[Alpha](-1-V[t,x,y])]-k c["Fe2+"][t,x,y]Exp[(1-\[Alpha])(-1-V[t,x,y])]),ElementMarker==2];
anode[Da_,k_,\[Alpha]_:1/2]=NeumannValue[-Da(c["Fe3+"][t,x,y]Exp[-\[Alpha](-V[t,x,y])]-k c["Fe2+"][t,x,y]Exp[(1-\[Alpha])(-V[t,x,y])]),ElementMarker==5];
bcs={noSlipBC,pressureDropBC};
ic={u[0,x,y]==0,v[0,x,y]==0,p[0,x,y]==0,V[0,x,y]==0,c["Fe3+"][0,x,y]==0,c["Fe2+"][0,x,y]==1/10,c["Cl-"][0,x,y]==2/10};
```

#### Second Question

Is this the proper way of setting generalized Neumann values for coupled systems? The boundary conditions I'm trying to achieve are given by:
$$
\boldsymbol{n} \cdot \boldsymbol{N}_{\mathrm{Fe}^{2+}} = -\boldsymbol{n} \cdot \boldsymbol{N}_{\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}} = D_a \left(c_{\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}} e^{-\alpha (U-V)} - K c_{\mathrm{Fe}^{2+}} e^{(1-\alpha)(U-V)} \right)
$$

### (Attempt at a) Solution

We attempt to solve the system of coupled pdes using:

```
z["Cl-"]=-1;z["Fe3+"]=3;z["Fe2+"]=2;
d["Cl-"]=1;d["Fe3+"]=1;d["Fe2+"]=1;
Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[{xVel,yVel,pressure,conc["Fe3+"],conc["Fe2+"],conc["Cl-"],voltage}=NDSolveValue[{fullSystemOfEquations[1,1000][{"Fe3+","Fe2+","Cl-"}]=={0,0,0,anode[1,1],cathode[1,1],0,0},bcs,ic},{u,v,p,c["Fe3+"],c["Fe2+"],c["Cl-"],V},{x,y}\[Element]emesh,{t,0,10},Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement","InterpolationOrder"->{u->2,v->2,p->1}}}},EvaluationMonitor:>(currentTime=Row[{"t = ",CForm[t]}])];],currentTime]
```

and get the error:

[image: LinearSolve::sing: Matrix SparseArray[<1078362>, {81124, 81124}] is singular.]

which makes me think the issue is with the boundary conditions.
Any advice would be appreciated!

### Helpful Resources

The [Mass Transport Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/MassTransport/MassTransport.html#509267359) has been helpful, but assumes the flow is parabolic and does not solve the fluid-mass coupled system.

## EDIT 01

Let's try a simpler problem. We'll drop the migration term in the mass transfer equation, and assume the overpotential $\eta = U-V$ is negative enough to only favour the reduction from Fe$^{3+}$ to Fe$^{2+}$.
This means that we have one fewer dependent variable, and we thus don't need the electro-neutrality equation. The simplified equations read:

- Incompressible flow:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{Re} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{u} &= -\nabla p + \nabla^2 \boldsymbol{u} + (\boldsymbol{J} \times \hat{e}_z) \\
  \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{u} &=0,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Mass Transfer (due to convection and diffusion only)
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{Pe} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}c_k + \nabla \cdot \left(- D_k \nabla c_k \right) + \mathrm{Pe}\; \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \nabla c_k  =0,
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- Current Density (due to the oxidising species alone):
  $$
  \boldsymbol{J} = z_{\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}} D_{\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}} \nabla c_{\mathrm{Fe}^{3+}}
  $$

which we can implement as:

```
z["Fe3+"]=3;z["Fe2+"]=2;d["Fe3+"]=1;d["Fe2+"]=1;
massTransportSimple[pe_][species_]:=
pe*{u[t,x,y],v[t,x,y]}.Inactive[Grad][c[species][t,x,y],{x,y}]+Inactive[Div][-d[species]*Inactive[Grad][c[species][t,x,y],{x,y}],{x,y}]+pe*Derivative[1,0,0][c[species]][t,x,y]
currentDensitySimple[oxidizingSpecies_]:=z[oxidizingSpecies]d[oxidizingSpecies]*Inactive[Grad][c[oxidizingSpecies][t,x,y],{x,y}]

fluidFlowSimple[rey_,pe_][oxidizingSpecies_]:=With[{lorentz=Activate@Cross[currentDensitySimple[oxidizingSpecies]]},
{rey( {u[t,x,y],v[t,x,y]}.Inactive[Grad][u[t,x,y],{x,y}]+Derivative[1,0,0][u][t,x,y])+Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][u[t,x,y],{x,y}],{x,y}]+Derivative[0,1,0][p][t,x,y]+lorentz[[1]],
rey({u[t,x,y],v[t,x,y]}.Inactive[Grad][v[t,x,y],{x,y}]+Derivative[1,0,0][v][t,x,y])+Inactive[Div][-Inactive[Grad][v[t,x,y],{x,y}],{x,y}]+Derivative[0,0,1][p][t,x,y]+lorentz[[2]],
Derivative[0,0,1][v][t,x,y]+Derivative[0,1,0][u][t,x,y]}]

fullSystemOfEquationsSimple[rey_,pe_][{oxidizingSpecies_,reducingSpecies_}]:=Join[fluidFlowSimple[rey,pe][oxidizingSpecies],massTransportSimple[pe]/@{oxidizingSpecies,reducingSpecies}]
```

[image]

Note we no-longer need to `Activate` the `massTransportSimple` equations, as it gets parsed correctly.
In-fact, using the modified simpler boundary and initial conditions:

```
noSlipBCSimple=DirichletCondition[{u[t,x,y]==0,v[t,x,y]==0},True];
pressureDropBCSimple=DirichletCondition[p[t,x,y]==0,ElementMarker==4];
reducingSpeciesFluxSimple[Da_,k_,\[Alpha]_:1/2]=NeumannValue[-Da(c["Fe3+"][t,x,y]Exp[-\[Alpha](-1)]-k c["Fe2+"][t,x,y]Exp[(1-\[Alpha])(-1)]),ElementMarker==2];
oxidizingSpeciesFluxSimple[Da_,k_,\[Alpha]_:1/2]=NeumannValue[Da(c["Fe3+"][t,x,y]Exp[-\[Alpha](-1)]-k c["Fe2+"][t,x,y]Exp[(1-\[Alpha])(-1)]),ElementMarker==2];
bcsSimple={noSlipBCSimple,pressureDropBCSimple};
icSimple={u[0,x,y]==0,v[0,x,y]==0,p[0,x,y]==0,c["Fe3+"][0,x,y]==1/10,c["Fe2+"][0,x,y]==0};
```

the solver does start, before complaining the system is stiff and the step-size is effectively zero:

```
Clear[xVel,yVel,pressure,conc]
$HistoryLength=0;
timeEvaluations={};
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel,yVel,pressure,conc["Fe3+"],conc["Fe2+"]}=NDSolveValue[{fullSystemOfEquationsSimple[1,10^3][{"Fe3+","Fe2+"}]=={0,0,0,oxidizingSpeciesFluxSimple[1,1],reducingSpeciesFluxSimple[1,1]},bcsSimple,icSimple},{u,v,p,c["Fe3+"],c["Fe2+"]},{x,y}\[Element]emesh,{t,0,1},Method->{"PDEDiscretization"->{"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement","InterpolationOrder"->{u->2,v->2,p->1}}}},EvaluationMonitor:>(AppendTo[timeEvaluations,currentTime=t];)];]
```

[image]

Any suggestions on ways forward would be appreciated!

Comment: Your first question: This could be the same bug as shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228692/parsing-error-bug-with-systems-of-nonlinear-pdes-mathematica-12-0-0).