# NDSolve: PDE parsing error leads to "inconsistent equation dimensions" when solving coupled diffusion equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve a system of coupled diffusion equations in 1D, but I can't use multiple terms in the flux. (In the language of [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html), I can't set the gamma term.) Here is the code:

```
(*define the operators*)

op1 = D[rho1[t, x], t] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-alpha1}} . Inactive[Grad][rho1[t, x], {x}] + {-alpha2}*
      Inactive[Grad][rho2[t, x], {x}], {x}];

op2 = D[rho2[t, x], t] + 
   Inactive[
     Div][{{-alpha1}} . Inactive[Grad][rho2[t, x], {x}] + {-alpha2}*
      Inactive[Grad][rho1[t, x], {x}], {x}];

(*No-flux boundary conditions: *)
bcConserved = NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == l];

(*define the parameters and ICs. f1 and f2 are just sigmoids with constrained integrals. : *)
alpha1=1;
alpha2=2;
tF=1;
l=1;
ic1 = rho1[0, x] == f1[x];
ic2 = rho2[0, x] == f2[x];

e0=0.1;
f1[x_] := (e0/l)*(20/(Log[20*(1 + E^(10*l))] - 
        Log[20*(1 + E^(-10*l))]))/(1 + E^(20*(x - l/2)));
f2[x_] := (e0/l)*(-(20/(Log[20*E^(10*l) (1 + E^(10*l))] - 
           Log[20*(1 + E^(10*l))]))/(1 + E^(20*(x - l/2))) + 2);
(*solve*)
sol = NDSolveValue[{op1 == bcConserved, op2 == bcConserved, ic1, 
   ic2}, {rho1, rho2}, {t, 0, tF}, {x, 0, l}]
```

The problem comes from the cross-coupling terms, e.g. `{-alpha2}*Inactive[Grad][rho2[t,x],{x}]`.

I know that gamma is supposed to be a vector (1D in this case), but I've tried various combinations of `{alpha2}*Inactive[]`, `{{alpha2}}.Inactive[]`, etc., to no avail. I have also tried `Inactive[Times][{-alpha},Inactive[Grad][rho_i][...]]`. Every time I get the same "Inconsistent equation dimensions" warning. I'm working in Mathematica 13.1, so I don't think it's the bug addressed in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228692/parsing-error-bug-with-systems-of-nonlinear-pdes-mathematica-12-0-0). What is going on?

Comment: ic1 and ic2 and tF are not defined.

Comment: Try `Inactive[Div][{-alpha2},vars]`

Comment: @user21, do you mean the following?
`Inactive[Div][{{-alpha1}} . Inactive[Grad][rho1[t, x], {x}] + 
  Inactive[Div][{-alpha2*rho2[t, x]}, {x}], {x}]`
If so, this yields the same error. If you mean having two separate terms:
`Inactive[Div][{{-alpha1}} . Inactive[Grad][rho1[t, x], {x},{x}]] + Inactive[Div][{{-alpha2}} . Inactive[Grad][rho2[t, x], {x},{x}]] `
then this runs. I have an untested suspicion that splitting up the terms is leading to numerical issues, but if this is the only way to proceed, perhaps that is a separate question.

Comment: Can you order your post such that it can be copied and pasted and gives the error message that you see?

Comment: @user21, done, thanks for your help. This is my first post, so apologies for the clunkiness.

Comment: Let me know what equation you want to model conservative convection or the gamma term and then I can send an inactive expression, but I doubt that the noise you apparently see comes from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understand what equation you want to model, but it should be much easier using the PDETerms, like this for example:

```
vars = {{rho1[t, x], rho2[t, x]}, t, {x}};
op = D[vars[[1]], t] + 
  DiffusionPDETerm[vars, {{alpha1, 0}, {0, alpha2}}] + 
  ConservativeConvectionPDETerm[
   vars, {{{0}, {alpha2}}, {{alpha2}, {0}}}]

sol = NDSolveValue[{op == {0, 0}, ic1, ic2}, {rho1, rho2}, {t, 0, 
   tF}, {x, 0, l}]
```

If the `ConservativeConvectionPDETerm` is not what you want then perhaps the `DerivativePDETerm` is, as you speak of a gamma term.

Here is the version with the derivative term instead:

```
op = D[vars[[1]], t] + 
  DiffusionPDETerm[vars, {{alpha1, 0}, {0, alpha2}}] + 
  DerivativePDETerm[vars, {{{alpha2}}, {{alpha2}}}]
```

Comment: The use of DiffusionPDETerm solved my problems with equation parsing, so thank you! Some numerical issues persist, but that's for another question.